# Can't connect to rdp in windows service

Tags: c#, service, rdp

I'm trying to log in to a server using rdp. I have a windows proces that automatically logs in to server using rdp. This is not working. When I monitor the server I don't see the user is logged in. This is my code:

```
public static void ConnectToRDP(string server, string user, string password)
    {
        Process rdcProcess = new Process();
        rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\cmdkey.exe");
        rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/generic:TERMSRV/{0} /user:", server) + string.Format(@"TEST\{0} /pass:{1}", user, password);
        rdcProcess.Start();

        rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe");
        rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/v {0}", server); 
        rdcProcess.Start();
    }
```

The code runs well when I start it from my local machine but after deployment to the server, it does not run. Any ideas?

Comment: perhaps this is a permissions issue on the deployment server.. do you have any network or server admins in your location..?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The deployment server is secured that's for sure. I'm going to check the permissions and I will get back to you.

Comment: Hi there I'm back again. I have checked but all permissions are set correctly according to the system administrator. Which permissions should be set? Can you give me more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in my code. I had set the domain on TEST hard coded in stead of changing it to the production domain. The code works fine and it connects to the remote desktop. I have made a change in the code:

```
public static void ConnectToRDP(string domain, string server, string user, string password)
    {
        Process rdcProcess = new Process();
        rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\cmdkey.exe");
        rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/generic:TERMSRV/{0} /user:", server) + string.Format(@"{0}\{1} /pass:{2}", domain, user, password);
        rdcProcess.Start();

        rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe");
        rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/v {0}", server); 
        rdcProcess.Start();
    }
```

Thanks for your time.